# Let $T: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\{0\}\cup X, X$ is a finite set. Only a finite number of integers are not sent to $0$. The set of all $T$ is countable?

Tags: analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

My tentative:

For some $T$, let $S$ be the finite set of numbers that are not sent to $0$. Then we can write $T$ as:

$$ T(x)=\begin{cases}
T(x), & \text{ if } x \in S \newline
0,& \text{ otherwise}  
\end{cases}$$

So counting the $T$ functions is the same that counting the $T_S$ functions ($T$ restricted to $S$) for all $S$

Then exists a finite number of $T_S:S\rightarrow X$ for a fixed $S$

Since $S$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, the set of all possible $S$ is countable.

Then total number of $T$ is a series with infinite countable finite terms, so the number of $T$ is countable.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct, be careful however, proving that the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ is not trivial (but it is true indeed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged this question with set-theory, the last conclusion should be justified more carefully.

Each $f\in T_S$ is a finite subset of the cartesian product $\Bbb{Z}\times X$.  So
$$T_S\subseteq \mathcal{P}_\text{fin}(\Bbb{Z}\times X) = \{Y\subseteq\Bbb{Z}\times X: Y \text{ is finite}\}$$

Also, the domain of each $f\in T_S$ is exactly $S$, so if $S_1\ne S_2$ then $T_{S_1}\cap T_{S_2}=\emptyset$.  We have then
$$\bigcup_{S} T_S\subseteq \mathcal{P}_\text{fin}(\Bbb{Z}\times X)$$
where the union on the left hand side is a union of mutually disjoint sets.  Since $\Bbb{Z}\times X$ is countable, so is $\mathcal{P}_\text{fin}(\Bbb{Z}\times X)$, and it follows that $\bigcup_{S} T_S$ is countable.  Finally, $\bigcup_S T_S$ is in a definable one-one correspondence with the original set of functions $T$ by extending each $f\in T_S$ by the value zero.

You might wonder why be so pedantic.  There is a more general theorem that says that a countable union of finite sets is countable.  But this more general theorem uses a weak form of the axiom of choice called $\text{AC}^\text{fin}_\omega$.  This axiom states that for any countable collection of non-empty finite sets, there is a function simultaneously choosing a member from each set.  On the other hand, in the specific problem you presented, it's possible to prove that $\bigcup_S T_S$ and the set of all $T$ is countable using the axioms of $\text{ZF}$ alone without any form of the axiom of choice.